# How to make a average dynamic function to be a helper and be able to reuse it when is need it

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

In my API built-in Node JS and MongoDB, I have to add a helper that universally can calculate dynamically the average of some rate fields where a client can rate from 0 to 5 a specific key value. 
Those values are added in the review collection and pushed inside the place collection where there are the same fields but those are for the average.

As an example I have this body to add a review:

```
{
    "Author": "Jo",
    "Text": "Something",
    "Rating": 4,
    "GoodService": 3,
    "WifiRate": 3,
    "QuitePlace": 3
}
```

When I send those on the other side I have the next response which is the average for the fields rates above:

```
    {
    "RateAverage": 3.9875,
    "GoodService": 3,
    "WifiRate": 3,
    "QuitePlace": 3,
    }
```

In the models, those values are default 0 and when I save those should change to show the AVG in a good way.

I tried this ugly way inside my controller but I want to make it as a helper function so I no need to repeat same stuff all the time and have the AVG calculated right away:

```
        place.RateAverage =
          place.RateAverage === 0
            ? review.Rating
            : (place.RateAverage + review.Rating) / 2;

        place.GoodService =
          place.GoodService === 0
            ? review.GoodService
            : (place.GoodService + review.GoodService) / 2;

        place.QuitePlace =
          place.QuitePlace === 0
            ? review.QuitePlace
            : (place.QuitePlace + review.QuitePlace) / 2;

        place.WifiRate =
          place.WifiRate === 0
            ? review.WifiRate
            : (place.WifiRate + review.WifiRate) / 2;

        place.save();
```

The entire controller as reference:

```
async postNewReview(req, res, next) {
    try {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle
      const userId = req.user._id.toString();
      const incomingData = {
        ...req.body,
        UserId: userId,
        PlaceId: req.params.placeId,
      };
      // RateAverage, GoodService, WifiRate,  QuitePlace
      const review = await DB.Review.create(incomingData);
      if (review) {
        console.log(review);
        const place = await DB.Place.findByIdAndUpdate(
          req.params.placeId,
          {
            $push: { Reviews: review },
            // RateAverage: (this.RateAverage + review.Rating) / 2,
            // GoodService: (this.GoodService + review.GoodService) / 2,
            // QuitePlace: (this.QuitePlace + review.QuitePlace) / 2,
            // WifiRate: (this.WifiRate + review.WifiRate) / 2,
            // $avg: { $sum: [4, review.Rating] },
          },
          { new: true },
        );

        place.RateAverage =
          place.RateAverage === 0
            ? review.Rating
            : (place.RateAverage + review.Rating) / 2;

        place.GoodService =
          place.GoodService === 0
            ? review.GoodService
            : (place.GoodService + review.GoodService) / 2;

        place.QuitePlace =
          place.QuitePlace === 0
            ? review.QuitePlace
            : (place.QuitePlace + review.QuitePlace) / 2;

        place.WifiRate =
          place.WifiRate === 0
            ? review.WifiRate
            : (place.WifiRate + review.WifiRate) / 2;

        place.save();

        console.log(place);
        if (place) {
          return res.status(200).send('Everything was updated successfully');
        }
        return res.status(500).send('Places was not updated');
      }
      return res.status(404).json('Not authorised');
    } catch (err) {
      Logger.error(err);
      return next(err);
    }
  },
```

As you see is not very nice but works in a way but I need an efficient way to have it outside the controller and to do the rates as like `2.9` just two numbers.

Comment: why are you using the ternary operator ? it will work fine even without ternary operator  .

Comment: I need an answer to the problem I have if you have please post an answer about it

Comment: do you  need a helper function  that do the average for you  ? or you need a helper function that do the average for these specific tables and colums

Comment: The preference will something I can reuse in different places a universal method if that possible and good to do it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/d6njzubm/12/ . please refer  the link

Comment: please refer the updated link

Comment: Ok and if I want to use with my controller specifically how I do that

Comment: you mean that you want to use the jsfiddle function in this controller ?  (pardon for my bad english)

Comment: I would like to understand how to use the helper with the controller as a reference so I can use other controllers too

Comment: you can define the helper in a file and than you can export that file in that particular controller.  and than you can use that function . you can try else i will give you an example

Comment: if you want than i can do this for you